# How to return a promise when an array of functions is passed, to another function as an arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

A question can be found [here](https://www.testdome.com/questions/node-js/get-in-parallel/51780?visibility=3&skillId=79):

> Implement the `getInParallel` function that should be used to invoke
> multiple API calls in parallel. The function accepts an array of
> functions that return a `Promise`. The function should return a `Promise`
> which should resolve to an array of results from the apiCalls
> argument.
>
> For example, calling the following code should print `[ 'First API call!', 'Second API call!' ]`:
>
> ```
> let promise = getInParallel([() => Promise.resolve("First API call!"),
>                          () => Promise.resolve("Second API call!")]);
> if(promise) {
>   promise.then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
> }
> ```

This is my solution:

```
function getInParallel(apiCalls) {
  // extract function one by one from array
  // then return each function's Promise to 'rFunt' as Promise.all only accepts array, iterable of promises as an input
  let rFunt = apiCalls.map((funct) => {
    return funct()
  })
  return Promise.all(rFunt).then((res) => {
    return res
  })
}

let promise = getInParallel([() => Promise.resolve("First API call!"),
() => Promise.resolve("Second API call!")]);
if (promise) {
  promise.then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
module.exports.getInParallel = getInParallel;
```

Are there any other ways/concept to solve this?

Comment: What is the problem with your current code that you want help with?

Comment: FYI, the `if (promise)` is not necessary as `getInParallel()` always returns a promise.  The `.then((res) => { return res })` is also not necessary and adds nothing as the promise already resolves to `res`.

Comment: @jfriend00 i am not facing any problem but i would like to know other solving methods, or alternatives!

Comment: This code could be cleaned up a bit as I noted in my previous comment, but this is the basic way you do this.  Nothing else to add here.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is pretty straight-forward, and maybe the simplest one.
I will rewrite `getInParallel` as below (usually we need type checking, omited here)

```js
const parallel = funcs => Promise.all(funcs.map(fn => fn()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is pretty close yet needs some modifications. Please check the code below:

```js
function getInParallel(apiCalls) {
  // Write your code here
  let functions = apiCalls.map(apiCall => apiCall());
  return Promise.all(functions).then(response => response);
}

let promise = getInParallel([
  () => Promise.resolve("First API call!"),
  () => Promise.resolve("Second API call!")
]);
if (promise) {
  promise.then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clean way to go about it

```js
function getInParallel(apiCalls) {
  // extract function one by one from array
  // then return each function's Promise to 'rFunt' as Promise.all only accepts array, iterable of promises as an input
  let resFunt = apiCalls.map((funct) => {
    return funct()
  })
  return Promise.all(resFunt).then((res) => {
    return res
  })
}

let promise = getInParallel([() => Promise.resolve("First API call!"),
() => Promise.resolve("Second API call!")]);
if (promise) {
  promise.then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
module.exports.getInParallel = getInParallel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short way.

```
function getInParallel(apiCalls) {
  return Promise.all(apiCalls.map(f=>f()));
}

let promise = getInParallel([() => Promise.resolve("First API call!"),
                             () => Promise.resolve("Second API call!")]);
if(promise) {
  promise.then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
module.exports.getInParallel = getInParallel;
```